# php: rewrite fields being wiped

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Hello I have website written in php where user’s can upload travel itineraries. It includes some Boolean fields, blank text fields, and image upload capabilities. A user can post an itinerary and then go edit the itinerary later.

I started to get reports from some users that when they were editing their itinerary, parts of it would be wiped (not all of it, just certain fields and image uploads). I was finally able to recreate this by creating an itinerary, editing it by adding very large photos then clicking post (upload) then immediately closing the window during the upload before it finished. (I had heard from users their Internet was weak or there were issues when hitting the server-so I figured this was the best way to recreate that experience). After closing the window, and returning to the site again certain fields were wiped and empty (not all fields-unfortunately just the most important). I would expect the experience to most likely just not save the upload changes and keep the old information.

I’ve been working with my dev team to figure out the issue but not sure what’s happening or if there are any tricks to prevent this.

Comment: Are you using AJAX to submit the form?

Comment: Please add the code responsible for the update of the itinerary. It's important to see how it is done in order to be able to have an opinion on what could happen.